# Using only input attribute for jquery on click

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to test my custom Jquery script using `type="button"` as selector.This is my first time doing this on WordPress.I can't use ids.

here is my code trying to test the alert function

```
function wpc_front_end_computation(){?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        $("input[type='button']").on('click',function()
        {
             alert("Test");
        });
    }
</script>
<?php}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpc_front_end_computation' );

function wpc_calc_frontend_func(){?>
<input type="button" value="Submit">
<?php}

add_shortcode('wpc_calc_frontend','wpc_calc_frontend_func');
```

I can't figure out whats wrong.When I click the button I can't get any alert.

Comment: And your question is...? What went wrong?

Comment: @Terry sorry,I updated it.I can't figure out what is wrong as my script doesn't work.The alert on button click doesn't trigger.

Comment: Is jQuery loaded? You did not specify that your `wpc_front_end_computation` has a jQuery dependency (when it clearly does). What does your console log say? What happens if you type `$.fn.jquery` or `jQuery.fn.jquery` in your console?

Comment: @Terry I haven't tried that.Although I did saw my script in the page when I view the page source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might have to do with the order in which these elements are being loaded into the DOM by WordPress, you can try change your jQuery to the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(document).on("click", "input[type='button']", function() {
    alert("Test");
  });
});
```

This should work in the event that your jQuery is loaded onto the page before your `input type="button"`

Comment: I tried this and work for me `add_action('wp_head', 'wpc_front_end_computation');` How come `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpc_front_end_computation' );` don't work?

Comment: It may be because in some cases scripts need to be registered before being enqueued with `wp_enqueue_scripts`